# drupal l() function external link does not work

Tags: php, drupal-7

I need a help with l() function. I want to create anchor to url which user sets in a administration form. It has to be an external link. I have set up the external option true, but the anchor still behaves like internal and the result is mydrupalpage.com/www.facebook.com instead of www.facebook.com

Could anyone help me with this? 
I am beginner in drupal so maybe I did something wrong in code:

```
 $output .= l(t('Facebook'),$variables['facebook_link'], array('attributes'=>array('external' => TRUE)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use attributes as the third parameter's index.

You just use the `array('external' => true)`:

```
 $output .= l(t('Facebook'),$variables['facebook_link'], array('external' => TRUE));
```

**Update from comments**

Besides the change above for the third parameter, the url in the second parameter needs to include the protocol:
`http://www.facebook.com` or `https://www.facebook.com`

If you do not include the protocol then `l()` will return a link relative to your website.

Comment: thanks, but it I have already used this and it also doesnt work.

Comment: I remember having a similar problem a while ago and one of the things that fixed it was to include the protocol (http or https) in front of my url. If you can't control what is in that $variables['facebook_link'], then maybe append it to the variable: 'http://' . $variables['facebook_link']

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Drupal output **my-domain-name/www.facebook.com** all the time.

You just need to **append 'http://' or some other protocol** to your links. Otherwise Drupal will consider this an internal link. Fixed it for me. Now it reads 'www.facebook.com'.